# Remove Rows With Same Value Across All Columns Using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset, and I need to remove rows if they are all empty or have same value across all the columns:

```
df <- data.frame(players=c('', 'Uncredited', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
                 assists=c("", "Uncredited", 4, 4, 3),
                 ratings=c("", "Uncredited", 4, 7, ""))


df

players      assists      ratings
<chr>         <chr>        <chr>
        
Uncredited  Uncredited  Uncredited
  C             4            4
  D             4            7
  E             3                                                                    ​               ​        ​
```

In our example, the 1st row is all empty and the 2nd row has the same value of `Uncredited`. Hence, the 1st two rows would be removed.

**Desired Output**

```
players assists ratings
 <chr>  <dbl>   <chr>
  C       4       4
  D       4       7
  E       3
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apply to loop over all rows and filter for those that have more than a single distinct value. Note that if all value in a row are empty the row also has only one distinct value, so the first condition is part of the second condition.

```
df[apply(df,
         MARGIN = 1, # rowwise
         FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1), ]
#>   players assists ratings
#> 3       C       4       4
#> 4       D       4       7
#> 5       E       3
```

Comment: Hi @mnist. Thank you for a great solution. We put `MARGIN = 1` for row. What would be for the column? I mean if a column is all empty or have same value across all the rows

Answer (score 4):

We could use `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_any(assists:ratings, ~ .x != players))
```

-output

```
  players assists ratings
1       C       4       4
2       D       4       7
3       E       3
```