# R: remove rows in data frame for which all columns contain same content or nothing

Tags: dataframe, duplicates, row, subset, multiple-columns

I have a data frame:

```
# create a data frame
V1 = c("gene_1", "gene_1", "", "")
V2 = c("gene_2", "gene_2", "", "")
V3 = c("gene_3", "gene_3", "gene_4", "")
V4 = c("gene_4", "gene_4", "", "")
V5 = c("gene_5", "gene_5", "gene_8", "")
V6 = c("gene_6", "gene_6", "gene_6", "gene_7")
df = as.data.frame(rbind(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6))
```

The data frame df looks like this:

> ```
>        V1     V2     V3     V4
> V1 gene_1 gene_1              
> V2 gene_2 gene_2              
> V3 gene_3 gene_3 gene_4       
> V4 gene_4 gene_4              
> V5 gene_5 gene_5 gene_8       
> V6 gene_6 gene_6 gene_6 gene_7
> ```

Now, I want to remove all the rows that have only labels of the same gene, resulting in:

> ```
>        V1     V2     V3     V4            
> V3 gene_3 gene_3 gene_4                  
> V5 gene_5 gene_5 gene_8       
> V6 gene_6 gene_6 gene_6 gene_7
> ```

I found several similar questions on stack overflow, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271399/removing-row-with-duplicated-values-in-all-columns-of-a-data-frame-r) but none of these solutions work for my exact issue. I feel like this should be easy, but I can't seem to find how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, based on another post that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74864508/remove-rows-with-same-value-across-all-columns-using-r):

```
df[df == ''] <- NA
df %>% filter(if_any(V2:V4, ~ .x != V1))
```

Gives:

> ```
>        V1     V2     V3     V4
> V3 gene_3 gene_3 gene_4   <NA>
> V5 gene_5 gene_5 gene_8   <NA>
> V6 gene_6 gene_6 gene_6 gene_7
> ```